# Django allauth redirecting to localhost from production

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, django-allauth

I have implemented django all auth and it works fine in devlopment. In production the redirect uri changes to `redirect_uri=http://localhost/accounts/google/login/callback/`. 
I am using gunicorn with nginx and tried setting `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` in the nginx configuration as well. How do I set the redirect uri to `http://example.com/accounts/google/login/callback/`?

Comment: I think you have to configure it in google develooper console. https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: On the redirect call the port gets missing from nginx. Callback from  localhost:9000 is already added in google console. Also on the redirect call the domain gets changed to localhost.